# When using weil or da, where does “gern” go to?

Tags: subordinate-clause

When using the word “gern” (or for that matter, nicht gern, am liebstem, sehr gern etc...), it hugs the verb. For example, ‘Gern esse ich Pommes.’

However, when using a word, such as “weil” or “da”, where does gern go?

E.g.   ... weil ich gern Fußball mag.

OR,  ... weil ich Fußball gern mag.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hugs the verb". You can say "Ich esse gerne Pommes", and that sounds more natural to me than "Gern esse ich Pommes". "Pommes esse ich abends gern" is also valid, and verb and "gern" are not next to each other.

Answer (score 5):

**Gern** or **gerne** follow the pattern of *nicht*. Place them before the item you want to focus:

> … weil ich gern Fußball mag. Nicht Tennis.

*… because I fancy soccer (in particular). Not tennis.*

> … weil ich Fußball gern mag. Nicht weil ich es spielen müsste.

*… because I (really) fancy soccer. Not because I had to play it.*